# p0123 - replaced TPS but still dies while driving

Tags: throttle, throttle-position-sensor, throttle-body, plymouth

My brother has a '96 Plymouth Voyager. He drove it to my place the other day and on his way home it died within a couple of miles. The check engine light was on so I pulled the codes and am getting a p0123. I cleaned out the throttle body and IAC, and replaced the TPS but that did not fix it. I'm still getting the same code and the same symptoms.

The car will start and drive for a few minutes, but then dies typically at low speeds. Sometimes it will start back up immediately and you can drive it a few more minutes, other times it won't start back up until after letting it sit for a few hours. I've checked for vacuum leaks and I can't find any. If anybody has any ideas of what to look into next I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the wiring. If it is a three wire switch check for 5v ref voltage. If you have access to the engine data and can get the tps voltage  it should be around 1v. You could also move the throttle and monitor the data with the key on and engine off. Voltage should go from 1v to nearly 5v. If you don't see any change you have a wiring or computer problem

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, I took the car in to my mechanic and he was able to diagnose that the problem was actually the crankshaft position sensor. Apparently that is a common problem on these Chrysler/Dodge vans and can result in a p0123.